# Solve non-linear system with positive integer constaint for solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

I bumped into a problem asking (in essence) to figure out the value of $b$ in the following system:

$b = a - n$

$bn = a + n^2$

All $a$, $b$ and $n$ need to be positive integers. Is there a systematic way of doing it?

I have substituted the first equation into the second and arrived at $n = \frac{a\pm\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a-8}}{4}$

So I know that $a$ has to be either 8 or a perfect square at the very least. I have manually found solutions for $a=8$ and $a=9$, both of which give a value of $b=6$. I know that these are the only solutions (according to Wolfram Alpha).

I was wondering how would I know there are no more solutions and if there is a more elegant way than to manually try values. The problem did ask for $b$ (not $a$ or $n$), in case that makes things simpler somehow.

Comment: Do you want solutions in integers?

Comment: Hint: subtracting the equations gives $\,b(n-1)=n(n+1) \iff b =n+\frac{2n}{n-1}\,$.

Comment: There are further integer solutions, e.g., $n=-1$ and $b=0$. Why are $a,b,n$ necessarily positive?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I want solutions in positive integers. $a$, $b$ and $n$ are necessarily positive because they represent quantities of an object. In the original problem, $a$ is the number of people in a school and $b$ the number of balls they can use. I omitted that information to not muddle the waters unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you, this helps! But one could imagine that there are situations with no balls, so with $b=0$. This still makes sense.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yep, I think b=0 would be acceptable, but n=-1, and n also represents a quantity of a real life object. Thanks for looking into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your second equation you know $a$ is divisible by $n$. Call It $a=qn$

The First equation becomes $b=(q-1)n$.
Substituting into the second equation and dividing by $n$
$$
(q-1)n=q+n
$$
Or $q=\frac{2n}{n-1}$ ($n\ne1$ by direct verification)

So $b=\frac{(n+1)n}{n-1}$. This is an integer iif $n-1$ divides $n+1$ i.e. iif $n=2 \text{ or } 3$ (try prove this) that gives $b=6$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'll look into proving the statement that n=2 or n=3 for n+1 to be divided by n-1 :) It feels intuitive (for larger values of n, the ratio is not even 2, so one can't be a multiple of the other, but I'd need no formalise that!)

Comment: @user2891462 It Is exactly how to prove It. Try to solve $\frac{n+1}{n-1} \ge 2$. Of course the ratio can't be one and has to be and integer